# Can word "complexity" be used as a synonym of word "confusion"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

**Can I say "complexity" in the meaning of confusion?**

I've been looking through translations of the word "complexity" that translator's listed and found word "confusion" as one of the meanings. Sometimes this translator can put in some excess results that doesn't exist in relation to word that I'm translating, so I think maybe it's the case, cuz other meanings don't have anything similar to the word "confusion".

Comment: Translation from what language?? Also, your question can easily be answered by looking at any dictionary and the difference in the two words exists in your language, most probably.

Comment: @Lambie from Russian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These do not mean the same thing: complexity has to do with how many pieces and parts and concepts there are in something, the more it has, the more complex it is. Confusion has to do with a person's perception of something; when they cannot think clearly about it, when their thoughts about it do not 'add up' and make sense, we say they are confused. We can also state that a situation is confused, meaning that it doesn't make any sense, at least to the speaker.

Complex things are thought of as easier to get confused about, but the words are not otherwise related. Something can easily be confused without being complex.

Confusion: chaos, addled, mixed-up, unclear, muddled. A thesaurus would do better, this is what I've come up with in a minute or two of thought for synonyms.